# How to get the text in front of or behind a specific character in a string

Tags: javascript, string

Let's consider two strings:

```
  var str = "Get Me @ Not Me";
  var str2 = "Don't Get Me @ Yep Get Me";
```

Let's consider a function named cutOut() which can do something like this:

```
 cutOut("frontOf", "@", str); // => Get Me
 cutOut("behindOf", "@", str2); // => Yep Get Me
```

Or if possible:

```
 cutOut("frontof @", str); // => Get Me
 cutOut("behindof @", str2); // => Yep Get Me
```

So how to make the cutOut() ? Can you make the cutOut() for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the simple example you gave, I would just use the base string split function:

```js
var str2 = "Don't Get Me @ Yep Get Me";
var parts = str2.split(/\s*@\s*/);
var frontof = parts[0];
var behindof = parts[1];
console.log("front: " + frontof);
console.log("behind: " + behindof);
```